# Json String to Map<> or List

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a json stored as string like below

```
String json="[{"name":"a","id",1},{"name":"b","id",2},{"name":"c","id",3}]";
```

My Question **how to encode this to a map or a list to get access to the keys and use the values?**

Comment: This is already a list of maps. The type `String` is invalid. It should be `List<Map<String,dynamic>>`.

Comment: check the edit I have it stores as a string

Comment: That's still invalid ;p because you can't have `"` inside a string delimited by `"` without escaping the inner `"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to JSON-decode the value first

```
import 'dart:convert';

final decoded = jsonDecode(json);
print(decoded[0]['name']); // just one example
```